# Mix Environment Debugging (C# Fortran) in VS 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, fortran

I have two visual studio projects, one written in C#, another written in fortran unmanaged code ( Intel Fortran compiler). Both of them are attached to one solution.

The C# is the frontend winform, whereas the fortran project is the backend.

Is there any tutorials that teach on how to step into code direct from C#?

Comment: Mixed-mode debugging is a pain, especially on x64 where it is completely unsupported.  The best approach I found was to simply debug the two chunks of code separately.  I heard promises made for VS2010, I don't know yet if that was delivered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [a solution here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/debugging-fortran-called-from-managed-code/).

Summary of above link:

When debugging a Visual Basic.NET, C# or other managed code application, you may find that the debugger will not stop at breakpoints in a Fortran DLL called from managed code.  To fix this, do the following:

1. In Visual Studio, right click on your managed code project and
   select Properties
2. Click Configuration Properties and then Debugging
3. Check the box Debuggers > Enable > Unmanaged code debugging
4. Click OK

[image]

Comment: It would be useful to put a synopsis of the solution here. There is no guarantee the info will remain on that site.